# Finding the last nonzero value and counting the columns after it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset of daily transactions per customer id, sample below. I'm trying to calculate the recency for each customer, the number of days since the customer's most recent purchase. In the context of the sample data, I want to count the number of days from `2018-04-14` since the last purchase: for id `1052` the recency would be 2.

```
trans_date  2018-03-01  2018-03-02  2018-03-03 ... 2018-04-12   2018-04-13  
   id                                                                                   
  1052         30.00       0.0         0.0     ...    14.00          0.0        
  1053          0.0        0.0         10.64   ...    0.0            0.0        
  1054          0.0        8.40        0.0     ...    0.0            9.10       
  1055          0.0        0.0         0.0     ...    0.0            0.0        
  1056          0.0        0.0         0.0     ...    42.21          0.0
```

I know how to find the last non-zero value in the row, but calculating recency using the column_index `trans_date` is where I'm stuck. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If always at least non `0` value use [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with change order of columns by indexing compared by not `0` value:

```
df['new'] = np.argmax(df.values[:, ::-1] != 0, axis=1)
print (df)
            2018-03-01  2018-03-02  2018-03-03  2018-04-12  2018-04-13  new
trans_date                                                                 
1052              30.0         0.0        0.00       14.00         0.0    1
1053               0.0         0.0       10.64        0.00         0.0    2
1054               0.0         8.4        0.00        0.00         9.1    0
1055               0.0         0.0        0.00        0.00         0.0    0
1056               0.0         0.0        0.00       42.21         0.0    1
```

If possible only `0` rows then solution above return wrongly `0`, so is necessary test it by [`numpy.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) and with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) add some value - e.g. `NaN`:

```
m = df.values[:, ::-1] != 0
df['new'] = np.where(m.any(axis=1), np.argmax(m, axis=1), np.nan)
print (df)
            2018-03-01  2018-03-02  2018-03-03  2018-04-12  2018-04-13  new
trans_date                                                                 
1052              30.0         0.0        0.00       14.00         0.0  1.0
1053               0.0         0.0       10.64        0.00         0.0  2.0
1054               0.0         8.4        0.00        0.00         9.1  0.0
1055               0.0         0.0        0.00        0.00         0.0  NaN
1056               0.0         0.0        0.00       42.21         0.0  1.0
```